# How to validate JSON request body before sending PUT request in python

Tags: python, json, request

It's when I send a PUT request to my API endpoint from python with a JSON request body I receive empty request body, because sometimes It's containing special characters which is not supported by JSON.

How can I sanitize my JSON before sending my request?

I've tried with stringify and parsing json before I sent my request!

```
profile = json.loads(json.dumps(profile))
```

My example invalid json is:

```
{
    "url": "https://www.example.com/edmund-chand/",
    "name": "Edmund Chand",
    "current_location": "FrankfurtAmMainArea,   Germany",
    "education": [],
    "skills": []
}
```

and My expected validated json should be:

```
{
    "url": "https://www.example.com/edmund-chand/",
    "name": "Edmund Chand",
    "current_location": "Frankfurt Am Main Area, Germany",
    "education": [],
    "skills": []
}
```

Comment: *"It's containing special characters which is not supported by JSON."* - There are no characters that are not supported by JSON. If certain characters appear to be missing after parsing, the code that creates the JSON is broken and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Okay thanks, wanted to mention about all the characters that are reserved and can not be used in JSON i.e **Tab** which to be replaced with "\t"

Comment: A JSON serializer will do all of this automatically, there is nothing that you need to replace manually, **unless** you are building JSON through string concatenation. And that's something you should absolutely never do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something quick to sanitize json data for limited fields i.e. current_location, you can try something like the following below:

```py
def sanitize(profile):

    profile['current_location'] = ', '.join([val.strip() for val in profile['current_location'].split(',')])

    return profile

profile = sanitize(profile)
```

The idea here is that you would write code to sanitize each bits in that function and send it your api or throw exception if invalid etc.

---

For more robust validation, you can consider using `jsonschema` package. More details [here](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/).

With that package you can validate strings and json schema more flexibly.

Example taken from the package readme:

```py
from jsonschema import validate

# A sample schema, like what we'd get from json.load()
schema = {
     "type" : "object",
     "properties" : {
        "url" : {"type" : "string", "format":"uri"},
        "current_location" : {"type" : "string", "maxLength":25, "pattern": "your_regex_pattern"},
     },
}

# If no exception is raised by validate(), the instance is valid.
validate(instance=profile, schema=schema)
```

You can find more infor and types of available validation for strings [here](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Rithin for your solution but that one seems more coupled with one field of the whole JSON.

I found a solution to replace it with below example code which works for any field:

```
profile = json.loads(json.dumps(profile).replace("\t", " "))
```